# Keycloack shows "Login timeout. Please sign in again." when using SAML

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to setup spring boot & spring security with keycloak (in a docker container). As an external IdP I have setup Microsoft Azure via SAML. The problem I am facing is that, after a successful login on Microsoft's side, keycloak displays an "Login timeout. Please sign in again." message.

I did test the login using keycloak's user system and the login works without a problem.
Some people who had a similar issue suggested that it might be a problem with docker's clock, but that is not the case here.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I did not change much from keycloak's default configs.

Edit:

```
Here's what the keycloak console says:
15:09:50,574 INFO  [org.keycloak.saml.validators.ConditionsValidator] (default task-53) Assertion _848dad26-2906-4b5c-8d40-f9fef9238800 is not addressed to this SP.
15:09:50,574 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.saml.SAMLEndpoint] (default task-53) Assertion expired.
15:09:50,575 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-53) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_RESPONSE_ERROR, realmId=<edited>, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.0.2.2, error=invalid_saml_response, authSessionParentId=<edited>, authSessionTabId=<edited>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Provide Keycloak logs, please.

Comment: @JanGaraj added to question

Comment: I would capture SAML request and compare it with SAML response - it looks like Azure generates different entity id - `is not addressed to this SP` (but that is only INFO). `Assertion expired` - double check if your system has clock synchronized + try to increase `Allowed clock skew` config value.